# Is there any function in SQLITE,to fetch count with DISTINCT and Date?

Tags: sqlite

I'm writing a select query to fetch count of rows with DISTINCT and where month of inserted date is same as present month.

My select query:

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT villageid) AS villages_visited 
FROM indexcard 
WHERE strftime('%Y',visiteddate) = strftime('%Y',date('now')) AND
      strftime('%m',visiteddate) = strftime('%m',date('now'))
```

The above select query gives me correct result only if one village is visited only once a month.but there are possibilities that user can visit same village maximum twice a month.

This is the rough structure of my table:

```
indexcard_no   villageid     visiteddate
1                   1         15/12/2018

2                   1         15/12/2018

3                   1         15/12/2018

4                   2         16/12/2018

5                   2         16/12/2018

6                   1         30/12/2018

7                   1         30/12/2018
```

Now what result i wish to get is count of villageid for month =12 must be 3.but the my select query gives count =2 as iam using DISTINCT.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that you get a result of **2** is that there are only **2** distinct village id's **1** and **2** (according to the data you have shown)

Additionally strftime will return null for dates in DD/MM/YY format as that is not a recognised date format. Dates should be in YYYY-MM-DD format (or another recognised format).

[SQL As Understood By SQLite - Date And Time Functions - Time Strings](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html)

perhaps what you are looking for is :-

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT villageid||visiteddate) AS villages_visited 
FROM indexcard
```

This will concatenate the villageid with the date for the DISTINCT clause, thus each visitid and date combination will then be considered as DISTINCT and thus the result would be 3 from your data.

---

## Working example :-

```
SELECT * FROM indexcard;
SELECT count(DISTINCT villageid||visiteddate) AS villages_visited 
FROM indexcard
```

### Results :-

#### 1st query all rows :-

[image]

- note additional column due to incorrect date being provided in the question.

#### 2nd Query :-

[image]

Comment: Actually dates are in YYYY-MM-DD format,but while posting this question by mistake i wrote it as DD/MM/YY

Comment: If i dont use distinct than i will get result count =7,as there are 7 entries in the tables.

Comment: Correct but that is irrelevant there are only two id's hence the result of 2. Change the last 2 rows (as an example) to **6 3 30/12/2018** and **7 3 30/12/2018** and the result will be 3 as there are now 3 different/distinct villageid's.

Comment: That is the issue i am facing with above query.As i mentioned earlier,if one particular village is visited once a month than above query is perfect to use.but if one village is visited twice a month,than the result is wrong.so what alternative can i use for distinct ?

Comment: I think I understand what you want and have edited the answer to what I think may be the solution.

Comment: Ok i will check the select query that you have mentioned above.

Comment: You must being doing something wrong. proof it works added to question.

Comment: The above query works because all the records are of same month.so when there will be records of other month then how will it filter records depending on present month ?

Comment: You add the where clause. I wasn't going to rewrite that when there is no need.

Comment: So to filter the records i used this:SELECT count(distinct villageid||visiteddate) AS villages_visited FROM indexcard WHERE strftime('%Y',visiteddate) = strftime('%Y',date('now')) AND strftime('%m',visiteddate) = strftime('%m',date('now'))

Comment: @Nisha Correct.

Comment: Of course remembering that **now** if run now would results in the year being 2019 and the month being 01 (another reason for dropping the where clause when testing)

Comment: I have some records for present month also.